# How to total by dynamic filtered group SSRS and Columns

Tags: reporting-services

Problem:
I would like to Total by the filtered “Campaign" but it includes all within the Campaign for the "result_type” code column and the value is a count of "det_interaction_id" text fields.  I am getting the incorrect Totals
Design View:
The design view has a filter in group properties by Campaign “*MORTGAGE*”

Output:

| Date | Campaign | AM | BD | EX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/10/2023 | MORTGAGE_123 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|  | MORTGAGE_678 | 48 | 1 | 0 |
|  | MORTGAGE_DEALER_321 | 16 | 0 | 0 |
|  | MORTGAGE_DEALER_PURCHASE457 | 464 | 3 | 4 |
|  | MORTGAGE_DOCS_213 | 16 | 2 | 0 |
|  | **Total** | 1,254 | 56 | 32 |

What I should get:

| Date | Campaign | AM | BD | EX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/10/2023 | MORTGAGE_123 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|  | MORTGAGE_678 | 48 | 1 | 0 |
|  | MORTGAGE_DEALER_321 | 16 | 0 | 0 |
|  | MORTGAGE_DEALER_PURCHASE457 | 464 | 3 | 4 |
|  | MORTGAGE_DOCS_213 | 16 | 2 | 0 |
|  | **Total** | 544 | 6 | 4 |

What I tried:
This normal Add Group Total `=Count(det_interaction_id.Value)`

`=IIf(Fields!Campaign.Value Like "*MORTGAGE*",Count(det_interaction_id.value),0)`

Comment: Assuming your report has row groups, then you should just be able to copy the expression from the detail rows. If this does not help, post a screen hot of the report design, making sure you show any row/column groups (the bit below the main design pane). Also show what expressions you are using in your 3 columns, AM/BD/EX

Comment: @AlanSchofield  I appreciate the response.  It wont allow me to paste an image yet. (I am new to stack overflow).  In the Design pane.  I have it grouped by Campaign ID in row pane and in the Column I have a field name result code.  The result code is the AM/BD/EX.  I had group filtered by the Campaign Name

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why this is but this worked for me to total dynamic column and filter by group

=SUM(IIf(Fields!Campaign.Value Like "*MORTGAGE*",1,0))

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that the IIF statement is only checking the FIRST Campaign value and not EACH value. The aggregate function should be on the outside of the IIF.

```
=COUNT(IIF(Fields!Campaign.Value Like "*MORTGAGE*", det_interaction_id.value, NULL))
```

I'm not sure how the total would be higher if the table is filtering for MORTGAGE, though.

Comment: I appreciate this.  I forgot to include but believe this is correct but still getting incorrect totals `=Count(IIf(Fields!Campaign.Value Like "*MORTGAGE*",det_interaction_id.value,0))`

Comment: @ReportLover - A COUNT of **0** is still **1** so the IIF isn't really doing anything in your example. The COUNT will ignore NULLs though. I was thinking of using SUM but was showing why your COUNT expression wasn't working.